# seaborn diverging cmap palette from HTML colors

Tags: python, seaborn

Seaborn has the option to choose [a pallet from any HTML color](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.light_palette.html#seaborn.light_palette) like so:

```
cmap = sns.light_palette("royalblue", as_cmap=True)
```

Is there a way to choose/create a diverging cmap using HTML colors? Something like:

```
cmap = sns.diverging_palette("color_a","color_b", as_cmap=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the point of `diverging_colormap` is that the endpoints differ only in hue, and have the same saturation and luminance values. That won't be true for two arbitrary html colors.

You can pass endpoints and a middle value to `blend_palette`:

```py
sns.palplot(sns.blend_palette(["dodgerblue", ".95", "crimson"], 9))
```

[image]

But note that the perceptual properties of such a colormap will be less good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sns.diverging_palette` (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.diverging_palette.html) by setting the values of your colour in [HSLuv system](https://www.hsluv.org/) as the first two arguments, setting the `hue`, eg.

```py
sns.palplot(sns.diverging_palette(200, 55, s=80, l=55, n=9))
sns.palplot(sns.diverging_palette(2, 165, s=80, l=55, n=9))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm aware of `diverging_palette`. My question is if/how to get this working without hue values, but instead with HTML colors